# one code works and the other doesn't in alpine.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

```
    @{
    int MOOD = 167;
}
<div x-data="{  variants: [] }" x-init="fetchVariants()" x-bind:data-product-id="@MOOD">

    <!-- Trigger for Modal -->
    <div x-text="JSON.stringify(variants)"></div>
    </div>
  
<script>
    function fetchVariants() {
        const productId = document.querySelector('[x-bind\\:data-product-id]').getAttribute('data-product-id');
        const url = `/Home/ProductDesc?ProductId=${productId}`;

        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                variants = res.variant.map(item => ({ price: item.price }));
                // Update the variants property with the new array of prices
               Alpine.store('variants', variants);

      //          console.log();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    }
</script>




<div x-data="{
    variants: []
  }"
     x-init="fetch('/Home/ProductDesc?ProductId=167')
     .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(res => {
    variants = res.variant.map(item => ({ price: item.price }));
    })"
    >
    <div x-text="JSON.stringify(variants)"></div>
</div>
```

the both code are same in my view but the above code doesn't work and the below code works ? what could be wrong as the above code is also same in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global [`Alpine.store()`](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store) object and the local [`x-data`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data) have different contexts. They serve different purpose. The global store object is good if you need to access/mutate some common data from multiple components. With `x-data` you create local properties that are accessible only for the component itself and all child components. But sibling components cannot access each other properties directly.

With this knowledge one can answer your scoping question. In the first version you have a local property: `variants`. In `x-init` you call `fetchVariants()` that fetches the data and put it inside an `Alpine.store` object. And we already know that these are different variables, so the local `variants` defined in `x-data` remains an empty array. You can fix this version if you use `$store.variants` in the template.

In your second example you use the local `variants` in the `x-init` not a new `Alpine.store` property, so this variable receives the new data and Alpine renders it in the template.

**Edit:** small example for `$store`:

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.store('variants', [1,2,3])
})
</script>

<div x-data x-text="JSON.stringify($store.variants)"></div>
```

Comment: you are talking about this  <div x-text="JSON.stringify($store.variants)"></div>

Comment: unfortunately it is not working if this is what are you talking about . can you post a code small code snippet of working code. it doesn't have to be the same example only what are you talking about

Comment: Sure, see my edited answer using `$store.variants`.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
@{
    int MOOD = 167;
}
<div x-data="{  variants: [] }" x-init="fetchVariants" x-bind:data-product-id="@MOOD">

    <!-- Trigger for Modal -->
    <div x-text="JSON.stringify(variants)"></div>
    </div>
  
<script>
    function fetchVariants() {
        const productId = document.querySelector('[x-bind\\:data-product-id]').getAttribute('data-product-id');
        const url = `/Home/ProductDesc?ProductId=${productId}`;

        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((variants) => {
                this.variants = variants;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    }
</script>
```

it outputted which was non existence

this also worked

```
<div x-data="{ data: null }">
<button @@click="fetchData">Fetch Data</button>

<div x-text="JSON.stringify(data.title)">
</div>
```

```
<script>
    function fetchData() {
        fetch('/home/getdata')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.data = data; // Assign the fetched data to Alpine.js data property
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            });
    }

    </script>
```